# Filter query in SQLAlchemy with date and hybrid_property

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I've got database table with columns year_id, month_id and day_id (all are NUMBER). I want to make a query which filters dates. In order to simplify it I want to add hybrid_property to join the mentioned fields together into date.

> ```
> class MyModel(Base):
>     __table__ = Base.metadata.tables['some_table']
>     @hybrid_property
>     def created_on(self):
>         return date(self.year_id, self.month_id, self.day_id)
> ```

But when I make query

> ```
> session.query(MyModel).filter(MyModel.created_on==date(2010, 2, 2))
> ```

I get an error `TypeError: an integer is required (got type InstrumentedAttribute)`.

Is there another way of doing such filter: I can't modify db schema (so the fields should remain the same), but at the same time it's difficult to compare dates against 3 separate columns?

Comment: If you are able to do it, I would recommend creating a computed column on the database with the `DATE` value. I am not sure about other RDBMS, but in MSSQL you can even persist computed columns and create indices on it. You will need to configure this columns also for SA accoringly (see http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/defaults.html#triggered-columns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an expression to your hybrid attribute, but it might be different depending on your RDBMS. See below for an example of one for `sqlite`:

```
@hybrid_property
def created_on(self):
    return date(self.year_id, self.month_id, self.day_id)

@created_on.expression
def created_on(cls):
    # @todo: create RDBMS-specific fucntion
    # return func.date(cls.year_id, cls.month_id, cls.day_id)

    # below works on Sqlite: format to YYYY-MM-DD
    return (func.cast(cls.year_id, String) + '-' +
            func.substr('0' + func.cast(cls.month_id, String), -2) + '-' +
            func.substr('0' + func.cast(cls.day_id, String), -2))
```

Comment: Dear all, please improve answer - simplify the date conversion for sqlite if you know it. Thank you.